# AngularJS Generate Select Options for Product Quantity

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope variable `max_product_stock` which stores the value of max quantity of the product that can be purchased.

If available stock is less than 10 then it will allow a maximum quantity purchase of what's in the stock **eg 4**.

However if more than 10 items are available in the stock then it should allow a maximum quantity purchase of 10.

Html:

```
<select>
   <option selected>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
if($scope.product.product_stock < 10) {
    $scope.max_product_stock = $scope.product.product_stock;
} else {
    $scope.max_product_stock = 10;
}
```

What I want to do is generate the options for the select element depending on the value of the max_product_stock (10 if value is 10 or value of max_product_stock if less than 10). So my question is how can i do this in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delcare a method in scope

```
$scope.getProductCount=function(start,end){
   var temp=[];
   for(var i=start;i<=end;i++){
     temp.push(i);
   }
 return temp;
}
```

Then call from html

```
<select 
     ng-model="selectedMax" 
     ng-options="n for n in getProductCount(1,max_product_stock)">
     <option value=""></option>
</select>
```